# How to find value in the map that starts with certain numbers

Tags: java, maps

I am stuck on an exercise, where I'm supposed to create a method that checks if a value of a map has a certain number chain at the beginning.

The project has to have 3 classes: Obywatele (citizens), RejestrObywateli (registry of citizens) and the Main. The class Obywatele (citizens) needs to have 3 String attributes (pesel, name, surname). Attribute `pesel`is a number (ID of a citizen in Polish). The first two numbers in the "pesel" declare the birth year of a citizen. 
For example for a pesel 96060501514, the birth year is 1996.

I am supposed to write a method in the class RejestrObywateli which finds all the citizens that are born before the 90s and prints them out.

Since the `private String pesel` is a String I tried to parse it into an Integer, but didn't know what to do next.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode

public class Obywatel {
    private String pesel;
    private String imie; // name
    private String nazwisko; //surname
}
```

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class RejestrObywateli {
    private Map<String, Obywatel> mapa = new HashMap<>();


    public void dodajObywatela(Obywatel o) {
        mapa.put(o.getPesel(), o);
    }
```

Comment: what if you have `19060501514` should I read it as 1919 or 2019?

Comment: What is the point of your map? `Obywatel` objects already contain `pesel` so you're basicly duplicating that data.

Comment: May be you look for `if (new Integer(Stringwith first two chars)) < 90) {}`

Comment: @YCF_L don't think it is really important in this question but according to Wiki you can tell the difference based on two next characters which normally define month. For ppl born between 1900 and 1999 its 01-12, for other year of birth you add some number to that, eg. for 2000-2099 add 20.

Comment: @YCF_L read it as 1919

Comment: @Amongalen I know right. But I did everything that is in the description of the exercise, except for the asked method.

Comment: Do you have to take into account people born after 2000 as well? or before 1900?

Comment: @Amongalen no, let's consider that all the citizens are born between 1901 -1999 :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all :

```
private Map<Obywatel, String> mapa = new HashMap<Obywatel, String>();
```

I don't think this structure can be helpful in the future.
whatever! to answer your question :

> I am supposed to write a method in the class RejestrObywateli which
>   finds all the citizens that are born before the 90s and prints them
>   out.

If you want to get only the keys(`Obywatel`) of the map then you can use :

```
List<Obywatel> collect = mapa.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(c -> Integer.valueOf(c.getValue().substring(0, 2)) < 90)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

else if you want to get the values(`String`) you can use :

```
List<String> collect = mapa.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(c -> Integer.valueOf(c.getValue().substring(0, 2)) < 90)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you want to print the keys and values :

```
mapa.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(c -> Integer.valueOf(c.getValue().substring(0, 2)) < 90)
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(String.format("k = %s, v = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is great, but I didn't implement it in my project since I don't think I have enough knowledge yet to use streams. I attached my solution below, if You could review it, I will be really grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the answers, but since I'm pretty new in Java, I didn't understand them in the mull manner. I did it in my own way - I would be grateful if You could review it. I created a list, to which I later add the correct search results and print it out at the end of the method.

```
public void findCitizen(int year){
    List<Obywatel> listOfCitizensBornBefore = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (String s : mapa.keySet()){
        if ((Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)) + 1900) < year){
            listOfCitizensBornBefore.add(mapa.get(s));
        }
    }
    if (listOfCitizensBornBefore.size() > 0){
        System.out.println(listOfCitizensBornBefore);
    }else{
        System.out.println("No citizen born before the given year");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sure you want to use `Obywatel` as key and `pesel` as value? Seems kinda stupid to me since `pesel` is already contained by the Object.

To parse a numberic string into an integer use: `Integer.parseInt()` or `Integer.valueOf()`

To get all values from a map use: `mapa.values()`

To get all keys from a map use: `mapa.keySet()`

You can also iterate over the map by using: `mapa.forEach((k, v) -> {})`

Answer (score 0):

it will be helpful to create a `toString()` Method to print the ones you find

```
/*
1. iterate through the map (access key value)     
    1a. Get the string (value) that contains the value you want to extract.
    1b. Extract the first two using string.substring(0,2);

2. Convert substring to integer using Integer.parseInt(substring);
    2a check if this integer is less than 90 (int<90)

3. if int is less than 90: `System.out.println(value);`
*/
```